# How do I install ios10 without a developer account?

Tags: iphone, ios

Apple announced iOS 10 during WWDC 2016. It looks amazing so I wanna install iOS 10 on my iPhone 6s. But I don't have a developer account of Apple.

Comment: You don't want to yet. It's incredibly buggy, all the widgets break (until us developers get to them) and many features (like Siri + apps and Messages + apps) just don't work yet. Battery life has been killed by the first beta, so it's obviously not ready for public consumption yet.

Answer (score 2):

Without any research on the matter I would say: you can't.

That's exactly what developer account are for: so a new software / a new system can be released to a small group of expert users. While the software / system may already look ok in a presentation, it probably still is way too buggy for the average user. So  either be patient, or become a developer.

Also, Apple has released the last few major OS upgrades (for both Macs and iPhones/iPads) as Public Beta some months before the official release. This will allow you do get your hands on these new versions some time between now and whenever-the-release-date-will-be.